# How to pass parameters to pipelines.py in scrapy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

The problem I have is basically a parameter problem.
I have a scrapy project with five spiders.
Spiders must extract information within a geographic area, which is delimited by user-entered coordinates.

At this point, the area polygon is defined in pipelines.py and is used by all spiders.
The question is, how should I pass the coordinates as a parameter from a graph interface (tkinter) to pipelines.py?

```
`class My_Pipeline(object):
    gmaps_key =   googlemaps.Client(key='some_key')
    count = 0
    insidePolygon = 0
    polygon = [(-30.8377119, -64.6603737),
              (-31.5156532, -64.6699867),
              (-31.5507684, -64.4969520),
              (-31.4898937, -64.3349037),
              (-31.3503690, -64.3150073),
              (-31.3052314, -64.3352658),
              (-31.2659561, -64.3623695),
              (-30.9873456, -64.3994484),
              (-30.8412493, -64.4173012),
              (-30.8117674, -64.4763527),
              (-30.8117674, -64.5642433),
              (-30.8377119, -64.6603737)]`
```

That polygon is the one that must be replaced by the coordinates entered by the user from the graphic interface.

Comment: where is user input (graphic interface) stored

Answer (score 1):

Pass parameters from command line using `scrapy crawl myspider -a params="1,3,5,6"`

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    def __init__(self, 
                 params='can be anything',
                 * args, ** kwargs):

        self.params = params

        super(MySpider, self).__init__()
```

and then in your pipelines

```
class My_Pipeline(object):
    spider.params #read if like this
```

Comment: I still get the message "spider is not defined" in "spider.params".

Comment: sorry, use `spider.params` in `process_item` method of pipelines